# Setting a default page margin for org latex export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, margins

So far, I have set `org-latex-packages-alist` to `'(("margin=2cm" "geometry"))`,
but if the geometry-package is explicitly loaded in a document, I get a [clash](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-optionclash).

I can use `\newgeometry{margin=1cm}` in the document,
but then latex produces errors on different configurations.

Is there a way to set the default margin (ideally through geometry)
without clashing with existing configurations in documents?

Comment: I can make a lot of guesses about what you are asking, but it would be better if you explained it. My main question is: if you include `geometry` in the packages alist, why would you explicitly load it again later?

Comment: Because I want the document to be usable with different emacs configurations, and margins is (in my works) a common thing to change.

Comment: What do those different emacs configurations share? How do they differ?  If options clash when you use them with `\usepackage`, how about *not* using them that way? You can make `geometry` an always-included package (without any options) and define the class(es) you use to set options in the preamble with `\geometry{margin=2cm}` afterwards (see `org-latex-classes`). If somebody uses `\geometry{margin=10cm}` later, I don't think that causes any clash. Assuming that works, would that answer your question?

Comment: Basically, I want the document to be usable on someone else's Emacs configuration, or a blank one. Isn't there some load-package-if-not-loaded-yet kinda macro in latex?
Edit: Found it, will add it myself

Comment: The Org mode document? Or the LaTeX document? The former will need *some* configuration on the Emacs side. The latter will need a TeXLive installation with all of the relevant packages. Neither is self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a good solution for my case: The [fullpage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) latex package.

> This package sets all 4 margins to be either 1 inch or 1.5 cm, and specifies the page style.

Which is exactly what I needed,
while I can still load `geometry` within the document to override it.

So I added it to my `org-latex-packages-alist`:

```lisp
(setq org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "fullpage") ("avoid-all" "widows-and-orphans") ("" "svg"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting this in the document will set a margin regardless of
whether the emacs configuration already loads `geometry`,
but it is a bit clunky and not DRY.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \makeatletter \@ifpackageloaded{geometry}{\geometry{margin=2cm}}{\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}} \makeatother
```

A solution that modifies my configuration rather than the document would be nicer.

Comment: `org-format-latex-header` is used for fragment I believe, not whole documents. You should check out `org-latex-classes` for whole documents as I pointed out in one of my comments.